# Hypergeometric equation and Schwarz's triangles

Tags: triangles, hypergeometric-function

I'm trying to understand how the hypergeometric equation relates to tiling the plane with triangles, and why this is the case when $a+b+c = 1$. I'm not looking for a rigorous proof but more of the intuitive idea behind it. I fear that I've got the wrong picture in my head and this is hindering my progress.